# Using AVRO from Python, for serialization only

Tags: python, avro

I would like to use Avro to standardize on a binary format for object serialization across different applications. The applications themselves will not communicate using Avro RPC. Probably something like ZeroMQ will be used.

I am trying to write a simple prototype where a Python client talks to a Scala server. I have no problem with the Scala side, but I am not so sure what to do on the Python side. I have tried to follow the [official guide](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html), as well as many blog posts.

Both in the guide and in the posts I have found, examples only show how to write/read from a file, or how to to RPC via Avro. I would like to be able to write an Avro byte representation of some object

- in memory, and
- without including the schema

I am fine with deploying a copy of the schema on both the sending and the receiving side, but the schema itself should not travel, since messages will be atomic, and I do not want the overhead of sending the schema on each and every request.

Is the above possible with the python avro library?

Comment: There's a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25130722/171236