# Encode an object with Avro to a byte array in Python

Tags: python-2.7, avro

In python 2.7, using Avro, I'd like to encode an object to a byte array.

All examples I've found write to a file.

I've tried using io.BytesIO() but this gives:

```
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'write_long'
```

Sample using io.BytesIO

```python
def avro_encode(raw, schema):
    writer = DatumWriter(schema)
    avro_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    writer.write(raw, avro_buffer)
    return avro_buffer.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 47):

Your question helped me figure things out, so thanks. Here's a simple python example based on the python example in the docs:

```
import io
import avro.schema
import avro.io

test_schema = '''
{
"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
'''

schema = avro.schema.parse(test_schema)
writer = avro.io.DatumWriter(schema)

bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
encoder = avro.io.BinaryEncoder(bytes_writer)
writer.write({"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256}, encoder)
writer.write({"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "red"}, encoder)

raw_bytes = bytes_writer.getvalue()
print(len(raw_bytes))
print(type(raw_bytes))

bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(raw_bytes)
decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schema)
user1 = reader.read(decoder)
user2 = reader.read(decoder)

print(user1)
print(user2)
```

Comment: If you want to run this under Python 3 change "schema = avro.schema.parse(test_schema)" to "schema = avro.schema.Parse(test_schema)"

Comment: quick question, when I try to write these stream of bytes into file and then save it on hdfs, the hdfs dfs -text command is not able to convert it back to string, apparently I am missing any step before writing the stream into file.

Comment: Is there any way to write `bytes_writer`  as avro file to s3 bucket?

Comment: `client.upload_fileobj(Bucket=aws.s3_bucket_name, Key=f'{s3_key}/{file_name}', Fileobj=bytes_writer)`
This way it creating file but content is empty.

Comment: and follow https://www.authentise.com/post/getting-started-with-avro-and-python-3

Answer (score -2):

Using `import avro` library we can't write the avro file with the schema.

To overcome this problem use `fastavro`
e.g.

```
import io
import fastavro
data = [{"name": "Shravan", "favorite_number": 256}, {"name": "Ram", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "red"}]
bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
fastavro.writer(bytes_writer, get_avro_schema(), data)
print(bytes_writer.get_value())
```

Comment: why can't we write the avro file with the schema?

Comment: I tried using `import avro` but, I did not able create avro file.
So I used `fastavro` library

Comment: But take a look at another answer in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25130722/7127824). There is a schema used. In particular, the following lines: `schema = avro.schema.parse(test_schema)` and `writer = avro.io.DatumWriter(schema)`

Comment: I mean ur answer might take place as `fastavro` alternative but the part with schema doesn't look like true