# how to use avro with python to serialize dictionary and write as bytes to bytesio to read and deserialize with schema correctly?

Tags: python, json, serialization, schema, avro

I want to use avro to serialize dictionary to produce bytestring, write it to io.BytesIO, read it and deserialize.

Q1: shall I load the schema from avro file as `avro.schema.RecordSchema` or can i load it from json file as `json with json.load`?

Q2: when `BytesIO` used shall I do `seek(0)` ?

Q3: I use `BytesIO` just so pass serialized bytestring to read it and deserialize. I want to do this in memory hence why I do not write / read file. is it ok?

```
import io
import json
import avro.io
import avro.schema

msg = {"name": "foo", "favorite_number": 1, "favorite_color": "pink"}

with open("schema", "rb") as f:
    SCHEMA = avro.schema.parse(f.read())

writer = avro.io.DatumWriter(SCHEMA)
bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
encoder = avro.io.BinaryEncoder(bytes_writer)
writer.write(msg, encoder)
b = bytes_writer.getvalue()

reader = avro.io.DatumReader(SCHEMA)
bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(b)
decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
deserialized_json = reader.read(decoder)
```

EDIT:

Documentation contains the example with serde and file write/read.
https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/gettingstartedpython.pdf

They use `DataFileWriter` and it does

```
verify that the items we write are valid items and write the appropriate fields.
```

according to documentation. if I don't use it and use DatumWriter only to write to BytesIO am I doing all ok? The documentation says I can use DatumWriter separately.

Comment: I specifically refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614588/encode-an-object-with-avro-to-a-byte-array-in-python